# Getting a rectangular parallelepiped's volume from 4 corners' 2D-coordinates

Tags: matrices, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a  movie of a rectangular parallelepiped growing.
I want to extract the volume/dimensions of the cube in time.
However the rectangular parallelepiped can be rotating/at angle with the camera.

I think it's possible to get the volume from the corners' picture coordinates since we know the corners are at 90° and side lengths are equal.
[Explanatory drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2hq1.png)

But I don't know where to start. I tried without success to look into matrix operations.

Comment: So what coordinates do you get out of the movie? as function of time?

Comment: Do you have a bird's eye view of the $xy$-plane?  In other words, if two corners have the same $x,y$ coordinates, do they overlap in your picture?  If you're using some kind of point perspective the problem is harder.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer. 
I added a drawing of the perspective and which points I think are useful.
The coordinates are the x,y pixel positions on the 2D images.
I have the intuition it shouldbe possible because there are many constants but not of how hard it actually is.

Comment: But what about the other corners of the parallelepiped's projection? They can be very helpful in determining what you want. And is the camera calibrated, i.e. do you know it's focal distance and the focal center on the projection plane?

Comment: I don't always see them all so I thought it was maybe possible with only 4

Comment: It doesn't matter if you see the corner points, if you see the four points that you show us on the diagram, you also see three of the edges that come out of each of these four points, right? That can determine how parallel lines project on the camera plane and can be very useful.

Comment: Also, do you know the parameters of the camera (calibration)? Like where the focal distance is (the shortest distance from the point of view of the camera to the projection plane of the camera) and where the closest point on the plane of the camera to the point of view of the camera is? However, if you

Comment: Without the camera info - such as FoV (angel to the corners), and orientation - there are many potential solution. What accuracy are you seeking?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, I see the edges
I think it would be easy to get the focal length. In addition, isn't the focal center just the center of my pictures ?
I'm looking for results that at least make sense compared to just the quick and dirty measure of a side length without any correction for angle or rotation.

Comment: @SimonLépinay Well, it is possible that the center of the picture is the center, but it might be that it is offset for some reason (like the picture being cropped, or the camera has some kind of specific center), who knows. However, having the necessary data allows you to find these camera calibration parameters.

Comment: @SimonLépinay According to me, it might not be possible to determine the exact volume or measurements of the parallelepiped. Not without a piece of information about a measurement in the real world that you know and what it corresponds to in the image, like for example knowing the distance between the camera and one of the points on the object at one specific moment of time.otherwise, you can determine everything up to scaling, so calculating the volume would be out question, but you may calculate the proportions of the edge-lengths of the parallelepiped.

Comment: @Futurologist I can sometimes get the dimensions for the last frame with a good accuracy. I guess that would do it. Otherwise it's possible to measure the scale via the measure of an object of known length.